# Activity handlers don't get removed

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I'm trying to get up to speed on using GWT Activities and Places.  I'm testing with some source code originally found on this good [blog post](http://www.bright-creations.com/blog/gwt-2-1-mvp-client-factory-example/).

I'm finding the Handlers that get added during bind() never seem to removed.  My little understanding of the [Activity javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/AbstractActivity.html) had me thinking they should get automagically removed by the time the Activity's onStop() method is invoked.

> All event handlers it registered will have been removed before this
>   method is called.

But each time I click a button the corresponding handler is called n+1 times.

What am I missing?  Please let me know if there is more info I can provide.

Here's a relevant snippet from the code:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AbstractActivity {

private List<ContactDetails> contactDetails;
private final ContactsServiceAsync rpcService;
private final EventBus eventBus;
private final IContactsViewDisplay display;
private PlaceController placeController;

public interface IContactsViewDisplay {
    HasClickHandlers getAddButton();
    HasClickHandlers getDeleteButton();
    HasClickHandlers getList();
    void setData(List<String> data);
    int getClickedRow(ClickEvent event);
    List<Integer> getSelectedRows();
    Widget asWidget();
}

public ContactsActivity(ClientFactory factory) {
    GWT.log("ContactActivity: constructor");

    this.rpcService = factory.getContactServiceRPC();
    this.eventBus = factory.getEventBus();
    this.display = factory.getContactsView();
    this.placeController = factory.getPlaceController();
}

@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget container, EventBus eventBus) {
    GWT.log("ContactActivity: start()");

    bind();
    container.setWidget(display.asWidget());
    fetchContactDetails();

}

public void bind() {

    GWT.log("ContactActivity: bind()");

    display.getAddButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            GWT.log("Add button clicked");
            ContactsActivity.this.placeController.goTo(new NewContactPlace(""));
        }
    });

    display.getDeleteButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            GWT.log("ContactActivity: Delete button clicked");
            deleteSelectedContacts();
        }
    });

    display.getList().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            GWT.log("ContactActivity: List clicked");
            int selectedRow = display.getClickedRow(event);

            if (selectedRow >= 0) {
                String id = contactDetails.get(selectedRow).getId();
                ContactsActivity.this.placeController.goTo(new EditContactPlace(id));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Events registered via. the `EventBus` passed to `AbstractActivity#start()` will be unregistered by the time `onStop()` is called. The event handlers registered in the above `bind()` method, however, are not registered via the `EventBus` and are not visible to the abstract base class. You need to unregister them yourself:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AbstractActivity {
  private List<HandlerRegistration> registrations = new ArrayList();

  private void bind() {
    registrations.add(display.getAddButton().
      addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { ... }));
    registrations.add(display.getDeleteButton().
      addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { ... }));
    registrations.add(display.getList().
      addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { ... }));
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    for (HandlerRegistration registration : registrations) {
      registration.removeHandler();
    }

    registrations.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your suggestion.  i am now able to unregister the handlers in onStop().  is it more common and better practice to pass the handlers via the EventBus in AbstractActivity#start()?  how is this done other than using @UiHandler?

Comment: The EventBus is for inter-application events, not UI events. You are doing things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found it best to handle registration in the view - make it responsible for only keeping one click hander active for each button.

Instead of:

```
class View {
    Button commitButton;

    public HasClickHandlers getCommit () {return commitButton;}
}
```

..and link to this in the Activity:

```
view.getCommit.addClickHandler(new Clickhandler()...
```

Do this in the View:

```
    class View {
        private Button commitButton;        
        private HandlerRegistration commitRegistration = null;

        public void setCommitHandler (ClickHandler c) {
            commitRegistraion != null ? commitRegistration.removeRegistration ();
            commitRegistration = commitButton.addClickHandler (c);
        }
    }
```

And the Activity:

```
view.setCommitHandler (new ClickHandler () ...
```

Hope that helps.